# How to add attachment for email laravel 6

Tags: laravel

this code is working but attachment is not attaching.  anyone can guide me to solve this

```
 \Mail::send('mail',$data, function($message) use ($replydata,$email){
               $message->to($email)->subject('reply for your add on mangala sewa');
               $message->attach(storage_path('storage/'.$replydata->HOR_IMG)); });
```

Comment: Make sure `storage_path('storage/'.$replydata->HOR_IMG)` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: In addition you can try `base_path('/relative-to-project/path/to/file')` as well.